# PIL how to resize image to fill up height and width dimension

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a set of images with random dimensions and would like to convert them to a standard size of (244,244). Using PIL Image resize() will convert the pictures to the right size, but there are black borders filling in the unfilled space, shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBuVK.jpg). I want to remove the black borders by stretching out the image out to fill the whole height and width
Here is the function preprocessing the pictures:

```
path = "data/oyaku_don_source/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
final_size = 244;

def resize_aspect_fit():
    for item in dirs:
        if item == '.DS_Store':
            continue
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            size = im.size
            ratio = float(final_size) / max(size)
            new_image_size = tuple([int(x*ratio) for x in size])
            im = im.resize((244, 244), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            
            new_im = Image.new("RGB", (final_size, final_size))
            new_im.paste(im, ((final_size-new_image_size[0])//2, (final_size-new_image_size[1])//2))
            new_im.save('data/Oyaku_Don/'+str(uuid.uuid4().fields[-1])[:5]+'.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

Any advice will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: There is lots of irrelevant code in your example. I suspect it won't even run, because `new_image_size` is undefined. Several variables are never used. Please provide a *minimal* example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason I was getting the black borders was because of the new_img. The image gets stretched out right after resize() so I saved the image right after.

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import uuid
#input path
path = "data/oyaku_don_source/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
final_size = 244;

def resize_image():
    for item in dirs:
        if item == '.DS_Store':
            continue
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            size = im.size
            ratio = float(final_size) / max(size)
            new_image_size = tuple([int(x*ratio) for x in size])
            im = im.resize((244, 244), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            #output path with a unique id
            im.save('data/Oyaku_Don/'+str(uuid.uuid4().fields[-1])[:5]+'.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
```